# Remove gaps from unused categories in plotly python facet group bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Is there an easy way to remove the gaps between the bars belonging to a single group? Just to make that clear, in my case the "actions" in the example data will never overlap across the facetting variable "animal", so these values will always be missing for the "other" "animal".

EDIT: as asked in comments, a gap within a subplot is desired (e.g. the category in general is used, only one instance is missing), to keep a consistent layout per subplot. Just the space reserved for categories exclusively belonging to another subplot should be removed.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [
    [1, 10, "dog", "run"], 
    [2, 15, "dog", "run"],
    [2, 13, "fish", "dive"],
    [1, 14, "fish", "swim"],
    [2, 13, "dog", "bark"],
    [1, 12, "dog", "growl"],
    [2, 12, "dog", "growl"],
    [1, 16, "fish", "dive"],
    [2, 7, "fish", "blub"],
    [1, 7, "fish", "swim"]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['day', 'temperature', "animal", "action"])

fig = px.bar(
        df,
        x=df["temperature"],
        y=df["day"].astype(str), # to use only existing values, 
        color="action",
        barmode="group",
        orientation="h",
        facet_row="animal",
        height=600
    )
fig.show()
```

[image: grouped_bar_plot_with_facets]

Comment: So, do you even want to remove the space that occurs from the missing value of `[1, 13, "dog", "bark"]`? (y is 1)

Comment: ah good point! I think this gap should actually stay, to get a consistent positioning per subplot. Thanks for asking!

Comment: I've found a solution that does what you want, but as separate bar charts, the one above the other. `Legend` will be separate for fish and dog, and temperature will be shown twice (1 for the top bar and 1 for the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried many things. The closest I got was by splitting the bars. I know it is not exactly what you want, but at least it is something close.

```py
data = [
    [1, 10, "dog", "run"], 
    [2, 15, "dog", "run"],
    [2, 13, "fish", "dive"],
    [1, 14, "fish", "swim"],
    [2, 13, "dog", "bark"],
    
    [1, 12, "dog", "growl"],
    [2, 12, "dog", "growl"],
    [1, 16, "fish", "dive"],
    [2, 7, "fish", "blub"],
    [1, 7, "fish", "swim"]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['day', 'temperature', "animal", "action"])

# take all unique animals
animals = df['animal'].unique()
print(animals) # prints ['dog', 'fish']

# for each animal in list, create the plot and print it
for a in animals:
    df_temp=df.loc[df['animal'] == a]
    fig = px.bar(
            df_temp,
            x=df_temp["temperature"],
            y=df_temp["day"].astype(str), # to use only existing values, 
            color="action",
            barmode="group",
            orientation="h",
            facet_row="animal",
            height=300
        )
    
    fig.show()
```

Please let me know if the solution satisfies you.

Comment: thanks for the effort...in the end I used separate traces in plotly graph objects instead of plotly express. In e.g. R ggplot2 you can just specify scales=`free_x`, so I was hoping there was a solution as easy as that